# Making footmisc work with manyfoot or bigfoot

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

How is it possible to get the `side` option of `footmisc` to work with the `manyfoot` or `bigfoot` packages?

The following displays the footnotes in the bottom of the page. The footnotes show on the sides when `bigfoot` is not used.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}

\usepackage[side]{footmisc}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}% adjust to your document's needs

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\footnoteB{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\lipsum[1-3]

Hello\footnote{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\footnoteB{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Here is my go at adapting Ulrike's answer:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}

\newcommand\sidefootnoteA[1]{%
   \footnotemarkA
   \marginpar{\footnotesize\addtocounter{footnoteA}{-1}\footnotemarkA\raggedright#1}}

\newcommand\sidefootnoteB[1]{%
   \footnotemarkB
   \marginpar{\footnotesize\addtocounter{footnoteB}{-1}\footnotemarkB\raggedright#1}}

\begin{document}

Hello\sidefootnoteA{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\sidefootnoteB{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\lipsum[1-3]

Hello\sidefootnoteA{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\sidefootnoteB{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

It fixes does put the notes in the margin, and it does a good job with counter A, which is numeric, but counter B doesn't get decremented, so I end up with `d` for the last note.

**Edit 2**:

The problem comes from `\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}`. Commenting it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it. I would do something like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\sidefootnote[1]{%
   \footnotemark
   \marginpar{\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotemark\raggedright#1}}

\begin{document}

Hello\sidefootnote{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\sidefootnote{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution to re-implement the `side` option of `footmisc`, but it doesn't solve the multi footnote levels problem which `bigfoot` addresses.

Comment: Also, the `-1` trick works with numeric counters, but not with letters.

Comment: I don't see how you want to place multi footnote levels in the margin. If you only want another numbering: define a `\sidefootnoteB`: `\newcommand\sidefootnoteB[1]{\footnotemarkB{}\marginpar{\addtocounter{footnoteB}{-1}\footnotemarkB{}\raggedright#1}}`

Comment: `footnote` is a counter. You can always add -1 to a counter, regardless how you actually print the value.

Comment: The footnoteB thing is precisely what I did. The A counter get decremented, but not the B counter. I'll post my code as an edit.

Comment: Hm. Thinking about it I think the second `\footnotemark` and the `\addtocounter` is a bit hackish. Better use `\textsuperscript{\thefootnoteB}`

Comment: Ah, that's nicer indeed :-)